# how can i setOnItemClickListener in this code And i wanted to check for the internet while app is running

Tags: android, json

//This is where the codes start actually.I want to open an activity from a listOnclick listner i have tried alot but i was not able to set the listners can someone please help me here i am i new bee

```
    BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    lvMovies = findViewById(R.id.lvMovies);

}
```

this is where i starts the Jsontask 
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

```
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_dry_clean:
                new JSONTask().execute("");
                return true;

            case R.id.press:
                new JSONTask().execute("https:/");
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
this is where AsyncTask starts.
public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<MovieModel>> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<MovieModel> doInBackground(String... params) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.connect();
            InputStream stream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }
            String finalJson = buffer.toString();

            JSONObject parentobject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
            JSONArray parentarray = parentobject.getJSONArray("movies");

            List<MovieModel> movieModelList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < parentarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject finalObject = parentarray.getJSONObject(i);
                MovieModel movieModel = new MovieModel();
                movieModel.setClothesname(finalObject.getString("clothesname"));
                movieModel.setPrice(finalObject.getInt("price"));
                movieModel.setImage(finalObject.getString("image"));
                ///adding the final object in the list*/
                movieModelList.add(movieModel);

            }
            return movieModelList;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (httpURLConnection != null)
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        }
        try {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<MovieModel> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.dismiss();
        MovieAdapter adapter = new MovieAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, result);

        lvMovies.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

}
```

// this is the adapter
    public class MovieAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
    private List<MovieModel> movieModelList;
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MovieAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<MovieModel> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        movieModelList = objects;
        this.resource = resource;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
            holder.tvMovie =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.clothes_name);
            holder.tvYear =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            holder.ivMovieIcon =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_view_icon);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
```

Comment: extend the array adapter then it will work

Comment: searchQuickResults.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().
                        beginTransaction().
                        replace(R.id.search_fragment_container,searchMainFragment)
                        .addToBackStack(TAG).commit();
            }
        });

Comment: bro i didnt get actually i am new at this can u please edit my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to start a new activity when an item in listview clicked?

you can use holder.setOnClickListener

otherwise, give us more details about what you want

you can use this code for RecyclerView adapter

```
public class MovieAdapterextends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieAdapter.OrderHolder> {

    private List<MovieModel> movieModelList;
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MovieAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<MovieModel> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        movieModelList = objects;
        this.resource = resource;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public OrderHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_video, parent, false);
        return new OrderHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final OrderHolder holder, final int position) {
        VideoObject videoObject = list.get(position);

//put your code here to set text for textview like that
        holder.txvTitle.setText(videoObject.getVideo_title());

        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                playVideo(videoObject.getVideo_code(), videoObject.getVideo_image());

            }
        });




        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             //write your code to start activity
Intent intent=new Intent(context,YOUR_ACTIVITY.class);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }


    public class OrderHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {


        private TextView clothes_name;
        private TextView clothes_name;
      private ImageView list_view_icon;


        OrderHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            clothes_name= itemView.findViewById(R.id.clothes_name);
            price= itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            list_view_icon= itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_view_icon);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: i have posted almost all the code here kindly check the question feed.

Comment: I encourage you to use RecyclerView instead of listView.
in getView method use
holder.setOnClickListener

Comment: thanks for replaying basically i dont know much about RecyclerView can u plz write a bit code for me .

Comment: Use RecyclerView instead of ListView and use this adapter.
see this 
https://traversoft.com/2016/01/31/replace-listview-with-recyclerview/

Comment: Thanks for helping me out ill watch a video then ill understand your code well again thanks for replying

Comment: Welcome.
it is not a video, it is an article on how to replace listview with recyclerview.
can you accept my answer, please?

Comment: Sure i think i habe seen u somewhere do u live in lahore

Comment: I have sent an email for you